# Launchpad: CLI "Copying packages"

Tags: command-line, ppa, launchpad

I'm using Launchpad to upload a `.dsc`, a `debian.tar.gz` and a `.orig.tar.xz`. The orig archive contains both i386 and amd64 files, and I use `debian/rules` to build different architecture packages. But it only builds on Trusty series. I would like to use the feature **Copy packages**, but I want it to be automated.

Currently, I have to connect to *Launchpad*, click *View Package Details*, click *Copy Packages*, and use:

```
> Destination PPA:
> This PPA

> Destination series:
> Utopic

> Copy existing binaries
```

Is there a way to automate all this "copy the existing binaries from the older series to the new series", or to do it through CLI to use it in a script ?

Thank you

---

Leads :

- **Q:** Maybe [`ubuntu-archive-tools`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-archive/ubuntu-archive-tools/trunk/files) can help me do that, it seem to have a copy-package python script ?

  **A:** It doesn't work with that: `python copy-package -y -b --ppa-name=myname/myppa --to-ppa-name=myname/myppa -s trusty --to-suite=utopic -e versionofpackage`
- **Q:** Maybe if I change my changelog entry from `trusty ; urgency=low` to `utopic trusty ; urgency=low` ?

  **A:** It doesn't work : `Unable to find distroseries: utopic trusty. Further error processing not possible because of a critical previous error.`
- **Q:** Build 1 `orig.tar.xz` and multiple `.dsc` & `debian.tar.gz`

  **A:** I currently build an incremented version-number (i.e. `mypackage-1.1.0-0trusty0` and `mypackage-1.1.0-0utopic0`), but the solution could be better since I have to reupload the `orig.tar.xz` for each and that it takes twice the place in the PPA since the built `.deb` aren't considered as a copy of each other but 2 packages.

Comment: For the record, you don't have to reupload the `orig.tar.xz` if you already uploaded it before. Run `debuild -sd` (or `dpkg-build-package -sd`) to generate a `.changes` file that doesn't upload the original tarball.

Comment: What error did you get with the first method?

Comment: Thanks for the first tip @saiarcot895, I'll use it !! 

The first method did not output anything, I think it's because `--to-suite` isn't made for "series" but for something else. I don't know. It seemed to work but nothing changed on my PPA.

Comment: `--to-suite` is for the series. I wouldn't specify the `-e` flag since, by default, the latest version will be chosen. Also, try splitting up `--ppa-name=myname/myppa` to `-p myname --ppa-name=myppa`, since `--ppa-name` just wants the name of the PPA. Also, you don't need to specify `--to-*` if it's the same thing as the from.

Comment: @saiarcot895 : I can't get copy-package to work. I have an authorization token, I'm the owner of the PPA, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy-package` is good for this, but the correct modern invocation would be:

```
./copy-package --from=~myname/ubuntu/myppa --from-suite=trusty --to=~myname/ubuntu/myppa --to-suite=utopic -b -y packagename
```

(As saiarcot895 correctly noted, you needed to separate `--ppa` and `--ppa-name`, but this was always very confusing which was among the reasons we added the unified `--from` and `--to` options for specifying archives.  Also, you neglected to include the package name, which was probably why you got no output; more recent versions of `copy-package` check for this.)